# Javascript recursion on fibonacii

Tags: javascript, recursion

Please see the below code -

```
function fib(x) {
    if (x === 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (x === 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2);
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions, basic questions on recursion.

1) When fib() is called recursively, wouldn't it go infinitely like n would take the value 0, -1, -2...... Since the above code works, which is the stopping condition?

2) If we remove the if() or else if() condition from above code, we get a maximum stack size error. Isn't one of the if or else if the stopping condition? or are both of them combined a stopping condition?

Comment: @surajck - if (x==0) is the stopping condition, then why do we get stack error if we remove the else if(x==1) part. I know in that case the code would not work, but we should not be getting the error, right?

Answer (score 1):

It stops because `x` eventually becomes `1` or `0`, in which case `fib` doesn't call itself anymore, because the `if (x === 0)` or `if (x === 1)` kicks in.

> or are both of them combined a stopping condition?

Exactly. You need both because `fib` calls itself both with `x-1` **and** with `x-2` (if `x` isn't `0` or `1`). If you remove the `else if (x === 1)`, think for a moment what happens when `x` is `1` and it calls itself with `x-2`. :-)

This can be more easily visualized if you add some instrumentation:

```js
function fib(x, indent) {
  var rv;
  
  log(indent + "fib(" + x + ")");
  if (x === 0) {
    log(indent + "Stopping (x is 0)");
    rv = 0;
  } else if (x === 1) {
    log(indent + "Stopping (x is 1)");
    rv = 1;
  } else {
    log(indent + "Recursing");
    rv = fib(x-1, indent + " ")+fib(x-2, indent + " ");
  }
  log(indent + "fib(" + x + ") returning " + rv);
  return rv;
}
fib(4, " ");

function log(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('pre');
  p.innerHTML = String(msg);
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```css
pre {
  font-family: monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Crowder -  if (x==0) is the stopping condition, then why do we get stack error if we remove the else if(x==1) part. I know in that case the code would not work, but we should not be getting the error, right?

Comment: @ridhimasingh: I didn't say `if (x === 0)` was **the** stopping condition, I said it was one of them (along with `if (x === 1)`). Look at the `else` condition in `fib`: It doesn't just call itself *once*, it calls itself *twice* -- with `x-1` and with `x-2`. So consider: If you remove the `else if (x === 1)` check, what happens when `x` is `1` and it calls itself with `fib(x-2)` (because you removed the `x === 1` check)?

Answer (score 0):

When the function `fib` is called at any point:

```
if (x === 0) {
    return 0;
} else if (x === 1) {
    return 1;
```

the above parts check if the parameter is either 1 or 0.

If not, the same function is recursively called in the else part:

```
} else {
    return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);
}
```

Each instance of the recursion also follows the above rules, so if any of the deep recursions  actually get called with 1 or 0, the chain breaks without further calls to the `else` part. And the results are cummulated.

As to why the stack error, because the recursion never stops if you dont have stopping conditions, there is no reason to stop calling the function! until all your stack is consumed!

Answer (score 0):

T.J. answered #1. I'll try to answer #2.

Let's analyze what happens if you drop the `x==1` condition:

- assume `x` is 2
- the code enters the `return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);` part
- `fib(x-2)` returns 0, which is fine (imagine now we have `return fib(x-1)+0;`, never mind the order)
- but `fib(x-1)` part enters the `return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);` part again:
- - Let's analyze that:
- - `x` is now 1
- - `fib(x-1)` returns 0, which is fine
- - but `fib(x-2)` goes into negative numbers **infinitely** and that's the problem, no more stops

The problem is, both of them are stopping combinations, you can't remove one. It's because the final return statement is made of **two recursive calls**, and if just one is stopped, the recursive calls will continue because of the other one (I'm specifically talking about this part: `return fib(x-1)+fib(x-2);`.

That's why we need **both `x==0` and `x==1`** to break the recursion when `x` is 2.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your **first question**, you have two possibilities:

1. Your input x is less than 0
2. Your input x is greater than or equal to 0

In the second case, your `fib` function has taken care of all the cases because when x is 0 or 1, your base cases are there to return a value (either 0 or 1) and when x is 2 or greater, your `fib` function will always make recursive calls which ultimately bring you to your base cases.

In the first case though, your `fib` function will fail because it will reach the maximum call stack. In other words, you don't have cases to handle negative numbers. Below is a potential way to address this:

```
var fib = function (x) {
  if (x < 0) throw new Error('x must be greater than or equal to 0');
  if (x < 2) return x;
  return fib( x - 1) + fib( x - 2);
};
```

To answer your **second question**, if you remove one of the `if` and `else if` statements, then you no longer have **BOTH** your base cases. The reason you need both is because you have a call to `fib(x - 1)` and `fib(x - 2)`. Think about it this way: if you only had the `if` condition and not the `else if` condition, what would happen when x is 1? Your function will try to make the following calls:

```
return fib( 1 - 1) + fib (1 - 2); // which is fib(0) + fib(-1)
```

When it tries to perform `fib(-1)`, you'll again get the maximum call stack error. The same logic can be applied to the other scenario where you keep the `else if` condition and removed the `if` condition.